# JaCoCo with microservice project architecture?

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

My project consists of 6 microservices in java and I am trying to figure out how to merge the html reports from Jacoco into one overall coverage report. As it stands now I end up with a report for each service and it would be nice to have an aggregated one so I can more easily put it into our CI for visibility etc.

I've tried various things I've found on web searches, but I end up with an empty coverage file when I try those suggestions.

Here is my gradle file:

```
subprojects {
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7+"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/customJacocoReportDir")
}
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "$buildDir/reports/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
test {
finalized by jacocoTestReport
...
}
```

I run gradle test to run the tests and get the report output per service using the above, but I am really stumped on how to merge them into a single html report. If anyone has done this successfully please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment we have the same kind of problem, the jacoco agent has a maven goal called "merge". You can specify the source files and run it:

**jacoco:merge**

***Full name:***

org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8-SNAPSHOT:merge

**Description:**

Mojo for merging a set of execution data files (*.exec) into a single file

**Attributes:**

- Requires a Maven project to be executed.
- The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
- Since version: 0.6.4.
- Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-resources.

> ```
> <fileSets>
>   <fileSet implementation="org.apache.maven.shared.model.fileset.FileSet">
>     <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
>     <includes>
>       <include>*.exec</include>
>     </includes>
>   </fileSet>
> </fileSets>
> ```

Actual link: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/merge-mojo.html

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I use `jacoco:report-aggregate` goal for this purpose.

According [its documentation](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html), I have a special module which is created just to run jacoco aggregation (it executes jacoco:report-aggregate during the "package" phase). It depends on modules whose test coverage I want to combine into a single report. This is also described by [techgobi.blogspot.com](https://techgobi.blogspot.com/2018/09/jacoco-multiple-module-aggregate-report.html).

As of version 0.8.8 of jacoco-maven-plugin, it has **non-obvious peculiarity**:
it works only if unit tests are executed by the same command as "*jacoco:report-aggregate*" goal.

In other words, if I use command-line to run unit tests from module A, and then I execute another command to run unit tests from module B, and then I execute "package" in the special module to trigger "*jacoco:report-aggregate*" - it won't work, JaCoCo will generate an empty aggregated report. In another scenario, it won't be empty, but the aggregated coverage will be 0%. It works only if unit test are executed by same command.