# How to configure multi-module Maven + Sonar + JaCoCo to get overall coverage report in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

From the past one week I am trying to get code coverage of my multi module project using Sonar. My project structure is as follows.

```
Web Service XYX
   +- pom.xml
   +-SubFOlder
   +- Module 1
      +- pom.xml 
   +- Module 2
      +- pom.xml 
   +- Module3
      +- pom.xml
```

Means I have one  folder in my directory and inside that I have all my sub modules. am able to generate a jacoco.exec file in all the sub modules target directory. Want to know the way to combine all these submodules jacoco.exec so that I can get a merged code coverage in sonar report.

Comment: am able to generata jacoco.exec file in all the sub modules target directory. Want to know the way to combine all these submodules jacoco.exec so that I can get a merged code coverage in sonar report.

Comment: I even tried the options <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath> and <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath> but no luck                                                                Appreciate if anyone provides solution.

Comment: What's currently showing up at your SonarQube dashboard for the reports? In my [project](https://github.com/Johnnei/JavaTorrent/blob/develop/pom.xml#L133) this is all I have for the configuration of Jacoco in my poms (besides the actual inclusions in the sub-modules poms). Please do note that I actually have both unit-tests and integration-tests in my modules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Johnei.   Sonar report is showing all zero values. I want to know the way to add sonar properties so that it can pick all the files(source,class,Surefire reports,jacoco.exec(important))) automatically from the respective folders(src/main/java, src/target/classes, src/target/surefire-reports respectively) instead of adding all the properties for each and every module.

Comment: In my project I defined the jacoco plugin in the 'pluginManagent' so I can selectively activate it in each module, so I expect that defining it as plugin in the root pom will activate for all. But as I'm in office i'm not in the position to test this.

Answer (score -1):

As I've answered [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003273/jacoco-with-microservice-project-architecture/39249295#39249295) You can put all the reports together in one folder (don't forget to call the different!) and use the merge mojo for that, or use a central unique file to all your reports by adding the flag "append":

```
-javaagent:append=true,destFile=/home/YourProject/report.exec
```

[Here](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html) you'll find more information about how to configure the agent.

Hope it helps!